# How to access my Android Application from Google Voice Assistance

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-voice, google-voice-search, google-voice-actions

I am developing an android application, let's say it for an instance as "RemindMe". In this application, I set alarms specific to application level. They are not system alarms.
My requirement is, after the opening of Google assistant (Ex: by saying "OK Google" followed by "What is my next alarm in RemindMe application", it should fetch next alarm from "RemindMe" application (No need to open the RemindMe app) and show in Google voice Assistant.

I checked DialogFlow (https://dialogflow.com/). I could not achieve my requirement.
Till date in my observation., Using DialogFlow, after opening the RemindMe app, I can say "what is my next alarm", I can fetch the next alarm time and show. But this is not my requirement where I want it without opening the app.

I checked Google custom Voice Actions - [https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions](http://Google%20Custom%20Voice%20Actions), I found a note saying - (***Note: We are not accepting requests for Custom Voice Actions. Stay tuned to Voice Actions - Google Developers and +GoogleDevelopers for product updates***).

Please let me me know if Iam somewhere incorrect or not clear.
Please help me in this. Thanks in Advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

What you will be looking for most likely is [*App Actions*](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/), which is going to open up to a developer preview soon. This system will allow applications to make content available through the Google Assistant by presenting actions that will allow the user to deep link into your application.

You can watch [the presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lu3L6DxUBRA) from I/O that goes into detail of how these actions can be created.

Comment: In this case,using this AppActions I can perform any customized operations of my app using Google Assistance like--"what is my next time in RemindMe app directly using Google Assistance

Comment: It will be more or less the experience you want. As the APIs aren't available yet, the developer experience may change.