# Use Google Assistant to directly talk to Android application and execute a task

Tags: android, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

I am working on an android project. I need to integrate the Google Assistant with this app. The requirement is very simple. I need to start the application using google assistance and ask to add a new question.

Example: "Hey Google, start myTestApp then navigate to questions (QuestionActivity inside my application) and add a new question".

So my question, is it possible to directly interact with my android app and is it possible to perform that task?

Thanks.

Comment: This is closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50507085/how-to-access-my-android-application-from-google-voice-assistance

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply.